# CopyTo() to a directory that doesn't yet exist

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

I want to copy the file c:\a1\b2\c3\foo.txt to d:\a1\b2\c3\foo.txt. The subdirectories don't exist on the D drive, and if I try to do a direct CopyTo() I'll get an IO exception. 
I haven't been able to find any built-in c# function that does the dirty work of creating the missing directories. So I wrote this:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"c:\a1\b2\c3\foo.txt");
DirectoryInfo destDir = new DirectoryInfo(file.DirectoryName.Replace("c:", "d:");

if (!destDir.Exists) // false
    CreateDirectory(destDir, null);
file.CopyTo(file.FullName.Replace("c:", "d:"), true);

private void CreateDirectory(DirectoryInfo endDir, Stack<DirectoryInfo> trail)
{
    if (trail == null)
    {
        trail = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
        trail.Push(endDir);
    }

    // remove last directory - c:\a1\b2\c3, c:\a1\b2, c:\a1
    Match theMatch = Regex.Match(endDir.FullName, @".*(?=\\\w*\Z)"); 
    DirectoryInfo checkDir = new DirectoryInfo(theMatch.ToString());
    if (!checkDir.Exists)
    {
        trail.Push(checkDir);
        CreateDirectory(checkDir, trail);
    }
    else
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in trail)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir.FullName);
}
```

That's pretty involved, and as they like to say on late-night informercials, "There's got to be a better way!"

Question: how would I make the function above move efficient? And am I missing a built-in method that already does everything I'm doing the hard way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\foo\bar\baz");
```

[Documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) as creating all required directories, and works for me.

> Any and all directories specified in
>   path are created, unless they already
>   exist or unless some part of path is
>   invalid. The path parameter specifies
>   a directory path, not a file path. If
>   the directory already exists, this
>   method does nothing.

Comment: I guess that does mean I was being way too involved. Thanks! That's what I was afraid of :)

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just use `Directory.CreateDirectory()` directly, since it already creates all the intermediate paths.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I am working with **CopyTo** and it creates all the subdirectories automatically in the destination location.

My code is as simple as can be:

```
// file is FileInfo and target is DirectoryInfo
file.CopyTo(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DirectoryInfo` instance can [create its own path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6esbt79(v=vs.110).aspx) with all the checking you want via `destDir.Create()`:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"c:\a1\b2\c3\foo.txt");
DirectoryInfo destDir = new DirectoryInfo(file.DirectoryName.Replace("c:", "d:");

destDir.Create(); // <-- makes it if it doesn't exist, otherwise noop

var newPath = 
   Path.Combine(destDir.FullName, Path.GetFileName(file)); // <-- just to be safe...
file.CopyTo(newPath, true);
```

Found this out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955425/1037948