# How do I create directory if it doesn't exist to create a file?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a piece of code here that breaks if the directory doesn't exist:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);
```

In one line (or a few lines), is it possible to check if the directory leading to the new file doesn't exist and if not, to create it before creating the new file?

I'm using .NET 3.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a folder does not exist, create it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, 
"Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha
If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/If-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it-using-C-

Answer (score 478, accepted):

#### To Create

`(new FileInfo(filePath)).Directory.Create()` before writing to the file.

#### ....Or, if it exists, then create (else do nothing)

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
file.Directory.Create(); // If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, content);
```

Comment: Elegant solution as it handles situations that require creation of nested folders.

Comment: Thank you! I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/, but I wanted to start with the absolute path to a file, and didn't want to deal with splitting the path. Now I know that you can access the Directory from the FileInfo instance.

Comment: Is there an async way to do this?

Comment: I suppose you could do it with `Task.Run(() => );`.

Comment: @JoePhillips, you could use `WriteAllTextAsync`

Answer (score 118):

You can use following code

```
  DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory` does exactly what you want: It creates the directory if it does not exist yet. **There's no need to do an explicit check first**.

Comment: Throws an IOException if `path` is a file and not a directory.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 46):

As @hitec said, you have to be sure that you have the right permissions, if you do, you can use this line to ensure the existence of the directory:

`Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath))`

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to move your file to an nonexistent directory is to create the following extension to native FileInfo class:

```
public static class FileInfoExtension
{
    //second parameter is need to avoid collision with native MoveTo
    public static void MoveTo(this FileInfo file, string destination, bool autoCreateDirectory) { 

        if (autoCreateDirectory)
        {
            var destinationDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(destination));

            if (!destinationDirectory.Exists)
                destinationDirectory.Create();
        }

        file.MoveTo(destination);
    }
}
```

Then use brand new MoveTo extension:

```
 using <namespace of FileInfoExtension>;
 ...
 new FileInfo("some path")
     .MoveTo("target path",true);
```

Check [Methods extension documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=VS.100).aspx) to check if the file exists and create it using [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=VS.100).aspx) if required.  Make sure you check if you have access to create files at that location.

Once you are certain that the file exists, you can write to it safely. Though as a precaution, you should put your code into a try...catch block and catch for the exceptions that function is likely to raise if things don't go exactly as planned.

[Additional information for basic file I/O concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336wast5(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: I initially mis-read your question that you wanted to write to a file that may not exist. The concepts are essentially the same for File and Directory IO though.

Answer (score -1):

`var filePath = context.Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLogFile"]));`

`var file = new FileInfo(filePath);`

`file.Directory.Create();` If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.

`var sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);`

`sw.WriteLine(Enter your message here);`

`sw.Close();`