# File.AppendAllText create subdirectory if doesn't exist?

Tags: c#

If I have a path `C:\Test\Test1\a.txt` and Test1 doesn't exist, how can I ensure it is created before appending to a.txt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create directory if doesn't exist to create file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955402/how-do-i-create-directory-if-doesnt-exist-to-create-file)

Comment: it's not duplicate! His question is "File.AppendAllText method create directory if doesn't exist?" not only directory creation!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename));
```

Comment: @Aks: Yes. "Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they already exist or unless some part of path is invalid."