# How to File.AppendAllText create subdirectory if doesn't exist?

Tags: c#

In c# how File.AppendAllText can create subdirectory if doesn't exist and i try this but it not working

```
File.AppendAllText("\\Logs\\date.txt", "Hi");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [File.AppendAllText create subdirectory if doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404849/file-appendalltext-create-subdirectory-if-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @Saragis, how this wouldn't come up in a search is beyond me, especially with an almost identical title...

Comment: @DangerZone I think we all know the reason.. the search button was never clicked. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the directory ahead of time.

See. [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the directory exists, and create it if it does not, like this:

```
string filename = "\\Logs\\date.txt";
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
if (!Directory.Exists(directoryName)) 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
}
File.AppendAllText(filename, "Hi");
```

Directory.CreateDirectory creates all directories and sub-directories, unless they already exist. This means you do not actually need to call Directory.Exists first, but that is my preference.

Comment: No need to check for the directory before calling CreateDirectory(). It will not create the directory if it already exists.

Comment: @Polyfun: it can not creat dir `Logs`

Comment: What error are you getting? You do need the correct permissions to be able to create the directory.